# How to get flex grow to work with shadcn scroll area?

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

Im trying to make a scroll area use flex grow so as to be the available height of the parent.

```
  <div className="w-4/5 px-[3%] flex flex-col flex-grow">
    <Navbar />
    <div className="flex flex-grow py-4 gap-x-4 items-start">
      <ScrollArea className="w-3/5 flex flex-col gap-y-4">
        <Stage />
        <SoldItems />
        <MyItems />
      </ScrollArea>
      <BidStream />
    </div>
    <UserProfileData />
  </div>
```

I tried some hacky stuff like h-[0px] but that didnt seem to work. The scroll area never scrolls but instead all the data is slapped on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

To make a scroll area use flex-grow and take up the available height of the parent container, you'll need to set the parent container's height to 100% and make sure that the scrollable area within it has a fixed or maximum height. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
<div className="w-4/5 px-[3%] flex flex-col flex-grow h-full"> {/* Set parent container to 100% height */}
  <Navbar />
  <div className="flex flex-grow py-4 gap-x-4 items-start">
    <ScrollArea className="w-3/5 flex flex-col gap-y-4 overflow-y-auto"> {/* Use overflow-y-auto for scrollable area */}
      <Stage />
      <SoldItems />
      <MyItems />
    </ScrollArea>
    <BidStream />
  </div>
  <UserProfileData />
</div>
```

In this code:

I set the parent container's height to 100% by using the h-full class.
I added overflow-y-auto to the ScrollArea element to make it scrollable when its content exceeds its maximum height.
By setting the parent container's height to 100%, it will grow to fill the available vertical space, and if the content inside the ScrollArea exceeds its height, it will become scrollable. This should give you the desired behavior of a flex-grow scroll area.

Comment: That solution sort of works, but if you look into the code of radix-ui's scrollarea, it won't make the proper element scroll and it won't use the radix / shadcn styles for scrolling. I still haven't found one that does, so it's probably the best for now. It's equivalent to replacing <ScrollArea /> with just a normal <div />